# 2 dataframes with same x-axes and facet_wrap plotted on the same graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

This file shows the code I wrote so far. 
I have the following two data frames and I would like to plot Var1 and Var2, which have the same x axis but different y axes on a single plot and split those over the 4 quarters.

Currently I am using the following code but as an output it gives me 8 graphs rather than 4.

Create my two data frames and they have the say weekdays and same quarters, however the scales used to measure each shall be different on the graph

```
weekday <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
quarter <- c("15Q1", "15Q2", "15Q3", "15Q4")
Var1 <- c(0.03, 0.5, 0.9, 2.3, 6, 3.4, 3.89, 0.08, 0.9, 1.2, 2.8, 8, 3.9, 5, 0.8, 2.7, 0.1, 7, 2, 3, 10, 2, 3, 1.9, 3.3, 4, 5.4, 6.89 )
dataframe1 = data.frame(weekday, quarter, Var1)

Var2 <- c(1000, 10001, 1500, 3000,2000, 3642, 2687, 2008, 5209, 4589, 3642,5336, 5342, 8962, 2301, 1365, 2300, 7412,3642, 3548,2355, 5698, 6538, 9856, 3142, 5962, 1253, 2100 )
dataframe2 = data.frame(weekday, quarter, Var2)

## I am plotting the first data frame here
## I assign the graph to a variable so it is easier to plot them. Its a bar chart            

g <-ggplot(dataframe1, aes(x = dataframe1$weekday, y = dataframe1$Var1)) + 
            geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
            facet_wrap(~quarter) + ##I am trying to separate them here
            labs(x = "Purchase Order Day", y = "Cycle Time", title = "Cycle Time Weekly Seasonality") ##I just rename the axes here

##I am plotting the second data frame here
##The second graph I am plotting should be a line

z <- ggplot(dataframe2, aes(x = dataframe2$weekday, y = dataframe2$Var2)) +
            geom_line() + 
            facet_wrap(~quarter) +
            labs(x = "Purchase Order Day", y = "Number of Orders per Day", title = "Number of Purchase Orders per Week")

##I am trying to bind the two graphs in here

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(bind(ggplotGrob(g), ggplotGrob(z), size = "last"))
```

Comment: When separating use `facet_grid(.~quarter)` and use facet_wrap when joining

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for combining the two plot formats. But with your data the problem is, that the y-values of the line plot are much higher than the bar plots, so you do not see them. I made a normalisation to the data, you can decide how to deal with it:

```
ggplot(dataframe1, aes(x = weekday, y = Var1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
  labs(x = "Purchase Order Day", y = "Cycle Time", title = "Cycle Time Weekly Seasonality")  +
  facet_wrap(~quarter) + 
  geom_line(data = dataframe2, aes(x = weekday, y = Var2/max(Var2)))
```

BTW: you can of course combine the two dataframes to one.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Hi J_F, thank you very much for your comment. I would like to combine them. The only issue is that I am unsure of how to get the count of the days in each quarter. So if we assume that Var2 is an order number, I would like to line which is plotted to represent the count of distinct orders on a Monday in each Quarter.